# Getting Execution Timeout Expired error only for 100 records

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I have an Azure Time Trigger function whose job is to read excel from FTP and add these details to the database. That excel has around 20K records, and for adding details, I have created a stored procedure that is using MERGE query for insert and update.
Last week am getting the following error
Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed before the completion of the operation or the server is not responding. Operation cancelled by the user. The statement has been terminated. The wait operation timed out.
This is the SP code

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UploadStudents]
    @userUDT [dbo].[UserUDT] READONLY
AS  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE Students 
    SET IsActive = 0, IsDeleted = 1 

    MERGE Students AS Target
    USING @userUDT AS Source
    ON REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Source.email, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '') = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Target.email, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')

    -- For Inserts
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (Id, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, CreatedBy, IsActive, IsDeleted, Email, UserName, PrimaryIdentifier, SchoolDepartmentCode, UserGroup, UserRole, SpiceId) 
        VALUES (NEWID(), GETDATE(), GETDATE(), NULL, 1, 0, Source.Email, Source.[name], Source.PrimaryIdentifier, Source.SchoolDepartmentCode, Source.UserGroup, Source.[Role], Source.SpiceId)

    -- For Updates
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
        SET Target.UserName = Source.[Name],
            Target.PrimaryIdentifier = Source.PrimaryIdentifier,
            Target.SchoolDepartmentCode = Source.SchoolDepartmentCode,
            Target.UserGroup = Source.UserGroup,
            Target.UserRole = Source.[Role],
            Target.[IsActive] = 1,
            Target.[IsDeleted] = 0,
            Target.ModifiedOn = GETDATE();
END
```

To solve this issue I have added an index on the email column,
And create a batch of 100 records and tried calling SP, but still got same time-out error.

Comment: what is the `CommandTimeout` of Sql object in your code? if you left the default, it would be 30sec. increase that in your code and check.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran F0r now it is default, I will increase and check, But 30sec should enough for 100row and before 1 week same code used to update 19k row at one time without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved by adding Primary key on UDT table which is input to stored procedure